# redirect_to :back not working properly in Rails 3 on windows system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using redirect_to :back in my controller action. But after executing the action, it is staying on that action and giving the following image:

[image]

After clicking on the redirected link, its giving template error which is right as the action on which it is redirected does not have a template.

And this is happening only on windows system. I am using Ubuntu as the development system and its working fine there.

Also I can't redirect it to specific path as the path may be custom defined by the user. So,I need to use back url only.

If anyone can figure out why this is so, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `request.referer`  instead of `:back`. If the user is coming through a link then this will be the previous page (or nil when directly navigating to the page)

Not the best but it's worth a try.

Comment: I have tried request.referer but its not working. On server side, referer is not getting captured. This is happening only on windows system.